# What's the best approach to implement this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

What would be the best way to write an algorith like:

```
if (a) {
  doA();
  done();
}
else if (b) {
  doB();
  done();
}
else if (c) {
  doC();
  done();
}
```

another approach I thought:

```
done = true;
if (a) {
  doA();
}
else if (b) {
  doB();
}
else if (c) {
  doC();
}
else {
  done = false;
}
if (done) {
  done();
}
```

Which is better? Is there another best approach?

Comment: Using a `switch` statement or even better polymorphic/overload language features seems way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Without any context, the most natural looking way for me is:

```
bool do_it(int condition)
{
    switch (condition)
    {
        case a: doA(); return true;
        case b: doB(); return true;
        case c: doC(); return true;
        default: return false;
    }
}

// ...

if (do_it) done();
```

since it abstracts the logic of "if this whole stuff succeeds, then do call `done()`".

But there are many other ways to do this. Especially, if the number of conditions will likely grow in the future, I wouldn't do that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many conditions/actions are there and kind of language you are using.

OOP and polymorphysm could work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` statement, setting an `isDone` flag along the way, and call done() based on the flag.

Comment: I dont think switch will work with different conditions. In some languages.

Comment: Especialy in c-like languages switch can be only used to compare one variable to multiple possible values. No complex conditions.

Comment: Nothing in his example makes me think a switch won't work. If he can't use a switch, then that's ok, it was just a suggestion, I'm not saying it's the ONLY way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If a,b and c are different complex conditional expressions then your first solution is the best. Maybe you can avoid the "else if" elements if this code is inside a function, like that:

```
private void doit() {
    if (a) {
        doA();
        done();
        return;
    }
    if (b) {
        doB();
        done();
        return;
    }
    if (c) {
        doC();
        done();
        return;
    }
}
```

So for me it is much more a code style question.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as

```
var failed = false;
if (a) doA();
else if (b) doB();
else if (c) doC();
else failed = true;
if (!failed) done();
```

I don't like setting a variable like `done` first to true and later undoing it, because the work is not done before the conditional starts, so it looks illogical.

I also don't like the switch case option because the conditions 'a', 'b', 'c' are not necessarily mutually exclusive; the if ... else if ... else cascade supports non-exclusive conditions but switch() might not depending on the language. E.g. you can't convert cascading if ... else's to switch in C++.

I think it's definitely important to remove multiple call points to done() because that's redundancy and later a maintenance issue if done() e.g. gets parameters.

Answer (score 0):

First, have one condition variable, not three. Second, I'd use a map of function pointers, with the condition variable as the key. Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def doA():
    pass
def doB():
    pass
def doC():
    pass
def done():
    pass

a = 3
b = 6
c = 8

doers = {}
doers[a] = doA
doers[b] = doB
doers[c] = doC
condition = a

# this is now the entire "algorithm":

if condition in doers:
    doers[condition]()
    done()
```